# Propio tipo de datos

Tags: string, haskell, type

Soy completamente nueva en Haskell y no logro entender como funcionan los data types. Sé que para este caso debo usar condicionales pero no entiendo como implementarlos, además, tengo claro que para mayor comodidad debería usar el split en otra función. A continuación explico el código:

Este fue el tipo que diseñé, ya que me lo solicitan.

```
type Line = [Classify]
data Classify = Plural String | Blank | Singular String
    deriving (Eq,Show)
```

Debo lograr convertir

```
function :: String->Line
```

Me dan un texto en String y debo clasificar las palabras que terminen en 's' como Plural. Blank son espacios en blanco, considerando que si es uno no cuenta pero si son dos hay uno, en caso de tres hay dos, etc. Singular es el resto de palabras. Ejemplo:

```
function "Hola como  estamos"
```

Debería retornar

```
[Singular "Hola", Singular "como", Blank, Plural "estamos"]
```

Answer (score 1):

El *data type* te da la pista de los casos que deberías considerar a la hora de crear la función. Se puede hacer de muchas formas, pero se entiende mejor si se ve todo en una sóla función, caso por caso:

```hs
import Data.List (drop, break)

classify :: String -> Line
classify "" = []
classify (' ':xs) = Blank : classify xs
classify xs | last ys == 's' = Plural ys : classify zs'
            | otherwise      = Singular ys : classify zs'
    where (ys, zs) = break (==' ') xs
          zs' = drop 1 zs
```

1. El primer caso, `classify ""` es el caso especial que nos sirve para terminar la recursión. A medida que procesamos la cadena, vamos acortando hasta llegar a la cadena vacía.
2. `classify (' ':xs)` simplemente es para tener en cuenta los espacios en blanco repetidos.
3. Con `(ys, zs) = break (==' ') xs` separamos la primera palabra, `ys`, del resto, `zs`. El resto puede ser vacío, si no hay más caracteres, o una cadena que empiece por espacio. Para quitar el primer espacio, mejor usar el `drop 1 zs` que el `tail`, ya que `tail` da error cuando `zs` está vacío.

Comment: No existiría un error en la línea 3 de la función? Por las variables de ámbito, exactamente en (' '::xs)

Comment: He corregido el código. Había puesto mal el operador _cons_ `(:)`.